# Free finite index submodule of $\mathcal{O}_L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of $p$-adic fields, with Galois group $G$. I've read somewhere that it is well-known that $\mathcal{O}_L$ contains a free finite index $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$-module, where $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ are the valuation rings. I'm triyng to prove this result, but I'm stuck.

My attempt: by the normal basis theorem, $L=K[G]\cdot \alpha$, where $\alpha=\beta/\gamma\in L^\times$. It is not hard to prove that we can assume $\beta\in\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\gamma\in\mathcal{O}_K$.  I believe that the module we are looking for is $\mathcal{O}_K[G]\cdot \beta\subseteq \mathcal{O}_L$, but I don't know how to conclude...

Comment: Not sure of what you are assuming, how did you define $O_K,O_L$ ? The goal is to prove that $\forall g\in G, O_L=g(O_L)$.

Comment: If you know that there is only one DVR above $O_K$ then it is immediate that $g(O_L)=O_L$. Usually $O_K$ is a DVR above $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $O_L$ is its integral closure in $L$, then the goal is to prove it is a DVR.

Comment: Once $\forall \in g\in G, O_L=g(O_L)$ then $(\sum_{g\in G} a_g [g]). b = \sum_{g\in G} a_gg( b)$ is a $O_K[G]$-module structure on $O_L$. That's why we need to know what you know about $O_L,O_K$.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I get your point, I forgot the word "free" so $\mathcal{O}_L$ was actually a solution of my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer my question.

FACT 1: $O_L$ is the integral closure of $O_K$ in $L$.
This is clear in the number field case, but it is also true for $p$-adic fields. See, for example, Neukirch, 'Algebraic number theory' (first step of the proof of Theorem 4.8 of Chapter II).

FACT 2: If $\alpha\in L$, then there exists an element $0\ne\gamma\in O_K$ such that $\gamma\alpha =\beta\in O_L$. In particular, $\alpha=\beta/\gamma$. This is Milne, 'Algebraic number theory', Proposition 2.6.

FACT 3: If $\alpha$ is a generator of a normal basis, then since $1/\gamma$ is fixed by every $\sigma\in G$, also $\beta$ is a generator of a normal basis.

FACT 4: $O_L$ is free of finite rank over $O_K$. This is Milne, 'Algebraic number theory', Proposition 2.29.

Now we show that $|O_L:O_K[G]\cdot \beta|<\infty$. Since $K\otimes_{O_K} O_L\cong L$ vía multiplication map, we have $$K\otimes_{O_K}O_L/(O_K[G]\cdot \beta)\cong L/(K[G]\cdot \beta)=0.$$ Nơw $O_L/(O_K[G]\cdot \beta)$ is a finitely generated over the PID $O_K$, so is has a free part isomorphic to some copies of $O_K$, and a finite torsion part. If it is infinite, then the tensor product with $K$ would contain some copies of $K$, and this would be a contradiction.